# Any suggestions on speeding this code up?

Tags: excel, vba, performance, palindrome

Ok, I have the code below, which takes 18 different words, all in Column A rows 1 to 18, and tries them in all different combos to find a seven word palindrome. I am pretty sure the code will get it done, but it just searches for a LONG time. I know there's a way to check the first and last letters of the combos, to make sure they're the same, before the code runs them through the REVERSE function, I just can't figure out how to do it. I am very new to this.In other words, each time it puts together 7 of the words, if it didn't have to go through the REVERSE function, a ton of time would be saved, and verification that the first and last letters match would do that. Thanks in advance for any help

```
 Sub SevenDrome()

Dim count As Integer

count = 0

Dim wordtest As String
Dim wordpal As String

For j = 1 To 18
   For k = 1 To 18
      For l = 1 To 18
         For m = 1 To 18
            For n = 1 To 18
               For o = 1 To 18
                  For p = 1 To 18

wordtest = Cells(j, 1) & Cells(k, 1) & Cells(l, 1) & Cells(m, 1) & Cells(n, 1) & Cells(o, 1) & Cells(p, 1)
wordpal = REVERSE(wordtest)

If wordtest = wordpal Then
count = count + 1

Cells(count, 7) = wordtest

End If
                  Next p
               Next o
            Next n
         Next m
      Next l
   Next k
Next j

End Sub
```

Comment: `18 ^ 7` iterations is... 612,220,032 iterations, and there are between 7 and 8 times more worksheet accesses and implicit code going on too. Luckily `count` is an `Integer` so this will all blow up at the 32,767th (`2^15-1`) increment, but this isn't about performance, it's about *algorithms*. I'd warmly recommend looking for palindrome questions on [codereview.se] (and read the answers!) - every single (on-topic) question on that site presents a working solution, that reviewers ...review - IMO CR is a good place on the Stack Exchange network to learn these kinds of things, check it out!

Comment: Thank you, I will definitely go check it out.

Comment: Unfortunately, there's nothing under palindromes for VBA

Comment: The nice thing about algorithms is that they are completely language-agnostic - a loop looks like a loop no matter the language...

Answer (score 0):

Try, This results in 104,976 which takes less than 2 seconds.

```
Sub test()
    Dim a(1 To 18)
    Dim vR(1 To 1000000, 1 To 1)
    Dim cnt As Long
    Dim i As Integer, k As Integer, l As Integer
    Dim m As Integer, n As Integer, o As Integer

    For i = 1 To 18
        a(i) = Range("a" & i)
    Next i

    For j = 1 To 18
        For k = 1 To 18
            If a(j) = a(k) Then
                For l = 1 To 18
                    For m = 1 To 18
                        If a(l) = a(m) Then
                           For n = 1 To 18
                              For o = 1 To 18
                                If a(n) = a(o) Then
                                    For p = 1 To 18
                                       cnt = cnt + 1
                                       vR(cnt, 1) = a(j) & a(l) & a(n) & a(p) & a(o) & a(m) & a(k)
                                       DoEvents
                                    Next p
                                End If
                              Next o
                           Next n
                        End If
                    Next m
                Next l
            End If
        Next k
    Next j
    Range("g1").Resize(cnt) = vR
End Sub
```

### Data image

[image]

### Result Image

[image]

**If each cell has more than 2 characters, you can do as follows.**

```
Sub test2()
    Dim a(1 To 18)
    Dim vR(1 To 1000000, 1 To 1)
    Dim cnt As Long
    Dim i As Integer, k As Integer, l As Integer
    Dim m As Integer, n As Integer, o As Integer

    For i = 1 To 18
        a(i) = Range("a" & i)
    Next i

    For j = 1 To 18
        For k = 1 To 18
            If a(j) = Reverse(a(k)) Then
                For l = 1 To 18
                    For m = 1 To 18
                        If a(l) = Reverse(a(m)) Then
                           For n = 1 To 18
                              For o = 1 To 18
                                If a(n) = Reverse(a(o)) Then
                                    For p = 1 To 18
                                        If a(p) = Reverse(a(p)) Then
                                            cnt = cnt + 1
                                            vR(cnt, 1) = a(j) & a(l) & a(n) & a(p) & a(o) & a(m) & a(k)
                                            DoEvents
                                        End If
                                    Next p
                                End If
                              Next o
                           Next n
                        End If
                    Next m
                Next l
            End If
        Next k
    Next j
    Range("g1").CurrentRegion.Clear
    If cnt Then
        Range("g1").Resize(cnt) = vR
    End If
End Sub

Function Reverse(s)
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim myS As String
    For i = Len(s) To 1 Step -1
        myS = myS & Mid(s, i, 1)
    Next i
    Reverse = myS

End Function
```

### Case 2 Data

[image]

### Case 2 Result

[image]

Comment: The assumption that `a(j)` needs to be equal to `a(k)` is wrong. Example (3 words): a,b,ba.

Comment: @BrakNicku, Depending on what the actual data format is, I think problems will arise.